# How to exclude the flutter plugin for certain versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, package, nfc

I use [flutter_nfc_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit) for new feature in my app but this package doesn't available for iPhone which iOS version is less than 13.
How can I exclude installing of this package for iOS which versions is less than 13?

Comment: how did you resolve it?

Comment: @HuyBuiDac by bumping iOS min version

Comment: I had the same problem with health plugin, I had to modify this plugin source code to support iOS 12 :(